# Google maps plugin doesn't work with popcorn.js

Tags: google-maps, popcornjs

I am trying to get the google map plugin to work with my video using popocorn.js but it doesn't show.

even the demo on their website doesn't work http://popcornjs.org/googlemaps

I am doing something wrong or there is some issue with the latest popcorn.js?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I need to start WAMP server. I thought I didn't need WAMP because everything is in HTML files but I was wrong